# Complex query using Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, querying

I have the following schema

```
table Std
--------------
id  int(11)
conf_id varchar(100)
name    varchar(255)
for_all_sponsors    tinyint(1)

table sts
------------
task_def_id int(11) NO
sponsor_id  int(11) NO
status  varchar(255)    NO
```

The join condition is sts.task_def_id=std.id.

Now, there may or may not be an entry in sts corresponding to std.

I want to write a query which reads something like this
"Get all entries in std which have for_all_sponsors=1 and conf_id set to 'c'. If there is a corresponding entry in sts with sponsor_id set to say '5' then get the status. If there is no entry with sponsor_id set to  '5', default to 'default status'."

The first part can be achieved by a left outer join and where sponsor_id=5.

The default status part is tricky. Is there a way to do this using a single query?

What is the most efficient way to do the querying,

### EDIT

What I have so far is

```
select * from std left outer join sts on std.id=sts.task_def_id where std.for_all_sponsors=1 and std.conf_id='c' and sts.sponsor_id=5;
```

Comment: The only part of this query, as you said yourself, that makes it more interesting than basic join and filter is the "default" status.  You're looking for a `CASE` statement - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: @Yuck and fqhv, I dont think both options work as here a record is getting generated out of thin air.

Comment: You have `sts.sponsor_id = 'x'`, but it is an int(11) column in your definition... is 'x' a placeholder for an int value, or is your definition wrong?

Comment: @Kateract Place holder. Let me fix that.

Comment: @SV Roberto's answer should have what you need

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
SELECT Std.*, 
    CASE WHEN sts.status IS NULL THEN 'default status' ELSE [status] END as Status 
FROM Std 
LEFT JOIN sts ON Std.id = sts.task_def_id AND sponsor_id = 'x'
WHERE for_all_sponsors = 1
AND conf_id = 'c'
```